# logrotate: what counts as rotation? single files or single executions?

Tags: logrotate

Let's ipothize I've a directory with 2 logs

- access.log
- error.log

My `logrotate` is configured for `daily` rotation with `10` as `rotation`

My question is: will I end up with 20 files or with 10 files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 files for each log (20 in this case) unless expressed in a separated config (see /etc/logrotate.d/ dir)

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my own question because I discovered how to manually launch `logrotate` against a single conf file, so I did tests.

I end up with `rotation count` files for *each* file matched by pattern, so 10x access.log and 10x error.log

Also, if my file has datetime, logrotation autodelete doesn't work as I hope because logrotate search .n or .date per each single file name.